# Airflow DAG Scheduling last day of month -n days

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to schedule my dag to run 3 days before the last day of month, so for Feb my dag should run on 25 whereas for march the dag should run on 28th day. Any ideas on how I could schedule this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Airflow >= 2.2.0**:

[AIP-39 Richer scheduler_interval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval) is available. You can define your own [Timetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/timetable.html) for the scheduling. There is How to guide [customize DAG scheduling with Timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html). You will need to register Timetable via plugin and define the scheduling logic.

**For Airflow < 2.2.0:**

you can schedule DAGs only if you can "say it" in a single cron expression. If your scheduling wish doesn't fit a cron expression then you can not set it out of the box. You can however find a cron expression that is close enough to what you wish like (`0 0 25-31 * *` - every day-of-month from 28 through 31 ) and place a `ShortCircuitOperator` in the beginning of your DAG that will verify if the date is actually 3 days before the end of the month. If the date is matched it will continue to execute downstream task if the date doesn't match it will skip the downstream tasks:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import ShortCircuitOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 8, 21)

}


def check_if_last_day_of_month(execution_date):
    #  calendar.monthrange return a tuple (weekday of first day of the
    #  month, number
    #  of days in month)
    run_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(execution_date.timestamp())
    last_day_of_month = calendar.monthrange(run_date.year, run_date.month)[1]
    # check if date is 3 days behind the last day of the month
    if run_date == date(run_date.year, run_date.month, last_day_of_month) - timedelta(days=3):
        return True
    return False


with DAG(
    dag_id='short_example',
    schedule_interval="@once",
    default_args=default_args,
) as dag:
    first = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id='verify_date',
        python_callable=check_if_last_day_of_month
    )

    second = DummyOperator(task_id='task')

    first >> second
```

Example run for the `2021-01-30`:

[image]

Example run for the `2021-01-28`:

[image]

Note: Make sure you are comparing the date that interests you. In the example I compared the `execution_date` of the DAG.

Comment: Hi I am aware about the conditional task (verify_date) in your example , that is one way of doing it for sure but I was hoping to just schedule it somehow in the cron expression. Is there a way to do that

Comment: @Infinite No, as explained starting Airflow 2.2.0 there will be better flexibility for scheduling.